# Proving a first order ODE solution is convex

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

let $y' = y - \sin y$ and and $u(x)$ is a solution in the open segment $I$ and $a, b \in I$. I need to prove that if $u(a) > 0$, then $u(b) > 0$, $u(x)$ is increasing and $u(x)$ is convex.

Now I know that $x - \sin x > 0$ for every $x > 0$ so if $u(a) >0$ then $u'(a) > 0$ and because an ODE solution is either fixed or strictly monotonous I get that $u(x)$ is increasing. If $u(b)= 0$ then $u'(b) = 0$ and if $u(b) < 0$ then $u'(b) <0$ but I've already shown that $u(x)$ is monotonous increasing therefore $u(b) > 0$.

My question is how can I show convexity of $u(x)$ from here? Can I just calculate $$
(y')' = y'' = (y - \sin y)'= y'-y'\cos y \Longrightarrow u''(x) \ge 0, x\in I $$ (because $u'(x) > 0$ for $x \in I$ and $\cos x \le 1$)?

Comment: Your proof works. You could add that $u$ is differentiable because it is a solution, hence $u - \sin(u)$ is differentiable, hence $u$ is twice differentiable.